# Cordova fails to build on android (GCM dependency)

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework

I have already installed the latest Support Repository package for Android.

However I cannot compile my new app with ionic/cordova (first build), and I get the following error:

```
TR: ~/Documents/bitron/B-See tommaso$ ionic run --device android
Running command: /Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See/platforms/android/cordova/run --device
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/share/java/android-sdk-macosx
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See/platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
         file:/usr/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/usr/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-gcm/
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.769 secs

/Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/webdev1/Documents/bitron/B-See/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
TR: ~/Documents/bitron/B-See tommaso$
```

This is my plugins list:

```
TR: ~/Documents/bitron/B-See tommaso$ ionic plugin list
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.1.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.7 "Keyboard"
nl.x-services.plugins.toast 2.0.4 "Toast"
TR: ~/Documents/bitron/B-See tommaso$
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is your cordova version? `cordova -v`  Could you post the relevant part of your `build-extras.gradle`?

Comment: And I don't have a file called "build-extras.gradle" :(

Comment: That is weird, because you haven't installed any plugin that would search for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+`.. Have you ever installed anything related to push notifications?

Comment: I did install phonegap-plugin-push from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

But then I removed it

Comment: `ionic state reset` should help you. But for future reference, even `phonegap-plugin-push` does NOT need to alter any gradle files.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it asap and see what I get :)

Comment: Let me know the result :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this removing and adding the platform again.

For some reason I still had some dependecies on an old plugin I uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks, this was the right answer for me. I always forget to do this - I definitely had all of the right SDK packages installed, just a cordova hiccup.

Comment: One thing that bothers me a lot is plugins all over the place when cloning or switching branches with a git repository... You'll always have to check for installed plugins and/or remove-reinstall them all. I wish they were just `npm` packages and install them with just `npm install`... lol

Answer (score 30):

In my case, this message was because of missing packages in the Android SDK, so it was required to install some packages via the Android SDK Manager.

```
android # To open the SDK manager
```

Look for:

```
Extras -> Google play services
Extras -> Google repository
```

And install them.

Comment: That the correct awnser, it's about missed android sdk packages.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: Hey I'm facing same issue
I didn't installed sdk manager or android library but doing remote build on adobe site
can you guide me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) you need to configure the gradle build system (File: build.gradle) to install the gcm plugin functionality.

e.g:

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0"
}
```

Attention: By using cordova the build.gradle file is automatically generated. That means that your additions will be lost every time you call `cordova / ionic build`

The cordova team advices to generate a `build-extras.gradle` file for custom configuration.

However, for me it is unclear how these files are merged :-( which leads to errors like that one you are facing.

Please read my [consideration here](https://github.com/akreienbring/GCMPushPlugin#android-install) to work around this problem.

Comment: I don't get why my new app (which is default template) won't even build.

That would mean that everyone should get this build error the first time they try to compile a new project